# Calculating score for quiz

Tags: python

Pretty much just a programming hobbyist.  Recently been trying to up my programming game by shortening my code.  Arrays would really help with that for this example, but I still haven't gotten them locked in yet.

Below I made homemade quiz.  If you run the script you'll see it will prompt the question for you to answer. Then, tell you if it is correct or incorrect upon answering.  The problem I can't solve is my variable "correct" outputs zero regardless of my if statements in the functions.  I defined it as zero to start somewhere but don't understand why it isn't adding to the final statement.

Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
    correct = 0
def answerA():
    if answer == 'a':
        correct = 0
        correct += 1
        print("Correct\n")
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
def answerB():
    if answer == 'b':
        correct = 0
        correct += 1
        print("Correct\n")
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
def answerC():
    if answer == 'c':
        correct = 0
        correct += 1
        print("Correct\n")
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
def answerD():
    if answer == 'd':
        correct = 0
        correct += 1
        print("Correct\n")
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")

answer = input("How many stars are in the sky?\nA. 100\nB. 1000\nC.10000\nD.Nobody knows.\n\nAnswer: ")
answerD()

answer = input("People who chew with their mouth open are what?\nA. Nice\nB. Detestable\nC. Considerate\nD. Mannerly\n\nAnswer: ")
answerB()

answer = input("which Star wars movie is a movie?\nA. Rise of the Sith\nB. Skywalker Strikes Back\nC. Revenge of the Sith\nD. Return of the Emperor\n\nAnswer: ")
answerC()

answer = input("Question 3: Which word below is spelled INCORRECTLY?\nA. Acommodate\nB. Pharaoh\nC. Separate\nD. Occurrence\nAnswer: ")
answerA()

print("Answers correct: " + str(correct))
```

Comment: You should read about variable scope: local vs global...

Comment: In each answer, you are incrementing the correct counter by 1 if its right, but resetting it to 0 if not. Regardless of previous answers, if you get the last one wrong will be 0. remove the 'correct=0' from inside each answer check as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `correct` to `0` after every `if` statement. Even removing it won't solve the issue as it will throw another error.

```py
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'correct' referenced before assignment.
```

Change your code to this -

```
def answerA():
    if answer == 'a':
        print("Correct\n")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
        return 0
def answerB():
    if answer == 'b':
        print("Correct\n")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
        return 0
def answerC():
    if answer == 'c':
        print("Correct\n")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
        return 0  
def answerD():
    if answer == 'd':
        print("Correct\n")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect\n")
        return 0

correct = 0        
answer = input("How many stars are in the sky?\nA. 100\nB. 1000\nC.10000\nD.Nobody knows.\n\nAnswer: ")
correct += answerD()

answer = input("People who chew with their mouth open are what?\nA. Nice\nB. Detestable\nC. Considerate\nD. Mannerly\n\nAnswer: ")
correct += answerB()

answer = input("which Star wars movie is a movie?\nA. Rise of the Sith\nB. Skywalker Strikes Back\nC. Revenge of the Sith\nD. Return of the Emperor\n\nAnswer: ")
correct += answerC()

answer = input("Question 3: Which word below is spelled INCORRECTLY?\nA. Acommodate\nB. Pharaoh\nC. Separate\nD. Occurrence\nAnswer: ")
correct += answerA()

print("Answers correct: " + str(correct))
```